# Cakephp 2 use the id of the record as index when retrieving data

Tags: cakephp, indexing, find, associative-array, containable

Is it possible to retrieve records where the index is the record id?

I have a model with a hasMany Relation. So my study can have multiple texts and questions etc.

The custom retrieve function looks like this:

```
    protected function _findStudyWithSequence($state, $query, $results=array()){
    if ($state === 'before') {
        $query['contain'] = array(
            'SubjectFilter'=>array('fields'=>'SubjectFilter.studyCode'),
            'Text'=>array('fields'=>'Text.position,Text.id,Text.text','order'=>array('position')),
            'Image'=>array('fields'=>'Image.position, Image.id','order'=>array('position')),
            'Video'=>array('fields'=>'Video.position, Video.id','order'=>array('position')),
            'Web'=>array('fields'=>'Web.position, Web.id','order'=>array('position')),
            'Likert'=>array('fields'=>'Likert.position, Likert.id','order'=>array('position')),
            'Question'=>array('fields'=>'Question.position, Question.id','order'=>array('position')),
            'Star'=>array('fields'=>'Star.position, Star.id','order'=>array('position')),
            'Multiple_choice'=>array('fields'=>'Multiple_choice.position, Multiple_choice.id','order'=>array('position'))
        );
        $query['recursive']=-1;
        $query['order']=array('Study.started DESC');
        $query['fields']=array(
                    'Study.id', 'Study.user_id','Study.title','Study.description','Study.numberParticipants','Study.state','Study.created','Study.modified','Study.started','Study.completed','Study.numberParticipants');

        return $query;
    }

    }
    return $results;
}
```

As you can see I am using containable
The results look like this:

```
array(
'Study' => array(
    'id' => '1845346986',
    'user_id' => '1402402538',
    'title' => 'bla bla',
    'description' => '',
    'numberParticipants' => '10',
    'state' => 'active',
    'created' => '2017-08-21 14:06:11',
    'modified' => '2017-08-21 14:29:56',
    'started' => '2017-08-21 14:30:06',
    'completed' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
),
'SubjectFilter' => array(
    'studyCode' => null
),
'Text' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'position' => '0',
        'id' => '1423909242',
        'text' => '<p>Bla <b>bla </b></p><p>blub</p><p><br /></p>',
        'study_id' => '1845346986'
    )
),
'Question' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'position' => '4',
        'id' => '729521908',
        'study_id' => '1845346986'
    )
), etc
```

But I want the Text and Question index to be the ids. Like this:

```
'Text' => array(
    (int) 1423909242 => array(
        'position' => '0',
        'id' => '1423909242',
        'text' => '<p>Bla <b>bla </b></p><p>blub</p><p><br /></p>',
        'study_id' => '1845346986'
    )
),
```

How can i manage this?

Comment: For CakePHP 3, use [`indexBy()`](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake\Collection\Collection::indexBy), but note that [the query needs to be executed first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328563/can-indexby-be-used-on-associations-directly-in-the-query/31346965#31346965)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CakePHP's amazing [Hash::combine()](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::combine) method.

Something like:

```
$results['Text'] = Hash::combine($results['Text'], '{n}.id', '{n}');
$results['Question'] = Hash::combine($results['Question'], '{n}.id', '{n}');
return $results;
```

It's not tested code, but I believe it's correct (or at least close), and you should get the idea from here.

Notes on `Hash::combine`:

> Creates an associative array using a $keyPath as the path to build its
>   keys, and optionally $valuePath as path to get the values. If
>   $valuePath is not specified, or doesn’t match anything, values will be
>   initialized to null. You can optionally group the values by what is
>   obtained when following the path specified in $groupPath.
>
> Hash::combine(array $data, $keyPath, $valuePath = null, $groupPath =
>   null)

Comment: It was correct before your last edit, `$results` is what needs to be modified, ie the `after` find data ;)

Comment: @ndm thanks, reverted (and yes, of course. I'll blame lack of coffee) ;)

Comment: Thank you for answering! This will work but it needs an iteration trough all results, right? There is not something like defining this in a model or in the containable?